# vue as nx plugin and using environment variables (nx-plus/vue)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, nomachine-nx

I've migrated vue app to nx, all is fine now except of one thing - previously, `.env` file was used in both dev and production environments, during development as well as build, `vue-cli-service` took care of that. Now I struggle with app build - it doesn't seem to read .env file, or I just do it wrong.

I've tried to add `dotenv-webpack` and add it in the `configure-webpack.js` but during build none of the variables was accessible. Here is the file example:

```
//.env
SOME_API_URL=$API_URL

// config.ts
export const CONFIG = {
  api_url = process.env.SOME_API_URL
}
// during build process.env is undefined
```

build command looks like this:

```
export API_URL='http://vue-app.com'; nx build frontend --skip-nx-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to switch to Vite but we’ve had good success using this plugin for our applications: https://github.com/chf007/vite-plugin-nx-dotenv